# Adding a static overlay logo into ffmpeg video stream and switch another which maintaining the logo

Tags: ffmpeg

I intend to add a logo and loop a set of pictures on top of a RTMP stream, my current command is as follows:

ffmpeg -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/xxx -i logo.png -f image2 -loop 1 -i prod.jpg -filter_complex [0:v][1:v]overlay=x=30:y=10[vt];[vt][2:v]overlay=x='if(lte(-w+(t)*100,200),-w+(t)*100+100,230)':y=10 -framerate 25 -r 30 -ar 44100 -c:a copy -b:a 20000k -movflags +faststart -preset medium -crf 1 -tune zerolatency -maxrate 20000k -vcodec libx264 -fflags nobuffer -g 60 -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 -f flv pipe:1

however I notice when it loops to a new prod.jpg file, the logo would disappear.

Thus I need some clues on command to loop the product pictures but maintaining the logo.

Comment: I assume you are updating the prod.jpg file. If yes, do all the images have the same parameters i.e. dimensions, format ..etc?

Comment: yes, I'm updating the prod.jpg file...they do hv same format and dimension

Comment: Replace `-loop 1` with `-stream_loop -1 -reinit_filter 0`

Comment: no luck, the logo still disappeared after updated the product image file...;(

Comment: actually it complains about invalid parameter -1 (I guess it points to -1 after -stream_loop); when I removed change '-1' to '1', it says 'Could not open file : 1'.

Comment: Show your full modified command.

Comment: /var/lib/snapd/snap/bin/ffmpeg -threads 1 -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/$key -i /home/apache/$key/logo.png -f image2  -stream_loop -1 -reinit_filter 0 -i /home/apache/$key/prod.jpg -filter_complex  "[0][1]overlay=x=30:y=10[v1];[v1][2]overlay=x=main_w-overlay_w-5:y=10[v2]" -map "[v2]" -map 0:a -framerate 25 -ar 44100  -c:a copy -b:a 20000k -movflags +faststart -preset medium -crf 1 -tune zerolatency  -maxrate 20000k -vcodec libx264 -fflags nobuffer  -g 60 -max_muxing_queue_size 1024  -f flv pipe:1

Comment: Which ffmpeg version?

Comment: ffmpeg version n4.3.1

Comment: I cant seem to find -reinit_filter option in ffmpeg documentation.

Comment: Wasn't documented when it was added a decade ago. Did so, now.

Comment: -stream_loop -1 is actually an acceptable parameter according to document, wonder why it still complains about it...any syntax error in my command?

Comment: i tested with -stream_loop -1 again, and it works now; but the first image still disappeared after i changed the product picture.

Comment: Apply it to both images.

Comment: yup, did that, and it works now....;)...thanks!